# Can a bean be a value to another bean in the Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to learn spring framework and bean configuration and so far it seems really cool.

I'm about to create a generic class to include all my Mysql functions and it needs to contain the DataSource. My question is: Is it possible to set the datasource already in the bean configuration?

If not then I'll need to set the class as singleton, create an init function and in the init function to do the following:

```
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) context.getBean("dataSource");
```

The question is, instead of doing that, can I 'inject' (donno if that's the right term)
it directly in the bean?

this is my bean configuration.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource">  
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />  
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foo"/>  
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>  
    <property name="password" value="password"></property>  
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
     <property name="initialSize" value="5" />  
 </bean>   

 <bean id="bar" class="foo.bar">
   <property name="dataSource" value="<HERE_SETTING_THE_DATA_SOURCE_ABOVE>" />
 </bean>
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: i think that is the main point of injection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [*reference*](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-ref-element) a bean like your `dataSource`.

Your class should have a member that can hold the `dataSource`:

```
package mypackage;

public class MyBean {

  private DataSource dataSource;

  public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = data.Source;
  }
}
```

Then you can inject the `dataSource` bean into this bean:

```
<beans>
  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource">
    <!-- set properties -->
  </bean>

  <bean id="myBean" class="mypackage.MyBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

That's it.